# Graph API - tagging people in a post, without a place

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, tagging

I'm building a webapp which lets users search for properties for sale, on a map. I want to be able to share the searches on Facebook and tag my friends, so for example I can say "I am searching for a house in Liverpool with [FB Friends]".

I've looked at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions for help tagging, but it seems to imply that I need a place ID to be able to tag people. 
It works if I infer the place using the Latitude/Longitude of my search, but is that acceptable?

I wasn't sure after reading the rules if I have to actually **be** in a place to tag it in a post.

Is it possible to create a post with the Graph API and tag friends, *without* having to add a Place ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts), I think it is impossible to do that.
In the 'Create' section, parameter 'tags' is noted that it should be used with parameter 'place'.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I found. I believe you can maybe do it with a custom action, but that wasn't suitable for what I was working on at the time...

Answer (score 0):

You can of course tag your friends without tagging places. See the Article `Tagging Friends` in the link you mentioned. Tagging friends and tagging places - both have no relation.